# Best way to update an table relationship reference in nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate

Say I have this.

A country has many products and a product can have many countries (many to many).

Now product A has

```
US
Canada
```

Now for some reason they stop selling product A in Canada. How do I update product A to remove the relationship as now product A is no longer in Canada.

Should I clear the list called like `ProudctA.Countries.Clear()`. Then go and add the countries still selected back in?

```
ProductA.Countries.Add(loadCountry(id)) // this would be a loop and I would be loading the ids from the select countries.
```

Or should I some how figure out what has changed and called like a delete or something?

I am getting a list of Guid back from the server. The user just sees a select list box and choose the countries.

When they edit the Product both US and Canada were selected but then they choose to unselect Canada so only the US Guid was sent back to the server as selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would do something like this

```
countriesToRemove = productA.Countries.Where(c => !selectedIds.Contains(c.Id)).ToList();

foreach(var country in countriesToRemove)
{
    productA.Countries.Remove(country);
}
```

however since you already loaded them (are in session cache) and the link table entries are removed and inserted anyway it would only matter if nothing is removed.